# Displaying data returned from Laravel API resource in a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

In laravel 5.7 applications, is it possible to create an API resource in a controller and display the result in a view? For instance, if i have a controller like this

```
public function index()
{
    return BookResource::collection(Book::all());
}
```

and this route in my api.php file

```
Route::get('books', 'BookController@index');
```

I will be able to see all books in postman when i make a get request to `../api/books`.

If I want to display the books in a view when a get request is made to `/books`, how will I do it? Here's my thought on how to go about it

1. create a route in web.php to get `books`
2. remove the api resource from BookController and get the list of books
3. add a function in the api.php get books route (return the book resource inside the function)
4. display data from controller in the view

Will that be the right way to go? Simply put the questions this way, how would you build an app and expose its api?

Comment: You need two routes - one to return the html view that includes the JS that will make the request to the second (the API route) which returns the data response.  Since you end up with lots of redundantly named things like "/books" and "/api/books" laravel now comes built with the two separate route files to keep it seperate. This file structure for routes is entirely arbitrary and up to you to manage however you wish. Sticking with the defaults will help if you get stuck and you need help. (this is a comment, not an answer b/c I don't know if this answers the question)

Comment: Using passport, it's very easy to consume your own api: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete routes, you can keep both the `api` and `web` routes to access your `Book` models.

Think like this: your books are stored in a database, your `web` and `api` routes are just 2 different ways to access that database, but they can (and *must*) live in separate files.

Basically you can have in `web.php`

```
Route::resource('books', 'BooksController');
```

and in `api.php`

```
Route::resource('books', 'Api\BooksController');
```

Comment: I get your point however if i set up my routes like this, what will my controller look like? Usually if I was build a simple app, then the index method of the controller would look like this `return view('home', compact('books'))`. With API resources the index method will look like this `return BookResource::collection(Book::all())` Now how can I pass the data returned to my view?

Comment: If you using APIs it means that you will receive data in JSON format (that's the standard) and you will consume it somewhere else (like a mobile app, or a command line software) so you don't have a view.

It's not really clear what you want to achieve, please be more specific and describe your scenario.